# Try Again and Retry functions for webservice/API calling in Android

Tags: java, android, api, view, android-volley

I have been trying to create a custom abstract class which can be used to handle different conditions before and after calling API using Volley in Android. I am handling cases like
1. If the internet is available to show progress else show retry button in inflated layout.
2. If API succeeds remove progress layout else show error in inflated layout.
How can we achieve this functionality?